# GUI environment ruined from attempting Hardware-assisted Virtualization

Tags: settings, themes, desktop, window-management, graphics

I followed the instructions from [Intel](https://software.intel.com/en-us/blogs/2012/03/12/how-to-start-intel-hardware-assisted-virtualization-hypervisor-on-linux-to-speed-up-intel-android-x86-emulator) to to speed up the Android emulator on my laptop. When I got to the part *"After the installation, you need to relogin so that your user account becomes an effective member of kvm and libvirtd user groups,"* I rebooted my laptop. However, once I got to the logon screen, the windows seemed different. Everything looks similar to the Windows 2000 look-and-feel and not like the default Elementary OS Luna look and feel. I uninstalled and purged everything the instructions told me to install, including their dependencies, and the environment still remains.

It wouldn't be such a big issue, except I can't click and drag programs, and there isn't any Close button on any of the program windows. Also, the programs open up in random portions of the screen, sometimes covering up the top toolbar or dock. How can I reset the GUI environment to the default?

Here are some pics:

[image]
[image]
[image]
[image]

I apologize for the bad quality, but they had to be taken by camera instead of screenshot because opening the browser and navigating and typing would be difficult due to the random placement of the programs and inability to move the window.

Comment: I was able to resolve this issue by reinstalling the [Pantheon desktop environment](http://tuxdiary.com/2015/06/27/install-pantheon-desktop-ubuntu/)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Abdul resolved this by **[reinstalling the Pantheon desktop environment](http://tuxdiary.com/2015/06/27/install-pantheon-desktop-ubuntu/)**